# Erlang how to pass parameter from module to another

Tags: erlang

I have an application written in erlang, i added a supervisor for distribution and now after parsing the configFile.cfg in the supervisor, i want to pass the configuration to my old application.
i have something like this now:

```
-module(supervisor_sup).
start() ->
    application_app:start().
```

what i want is:

```
-module(supervisor_sup).

-record(config,{param1,param2}).
%After parsing the configFile.cfg
Conf = #config{param1 = Param1,
            param2 = Param2},

start(Conf) ->
    application_app:start(Conf).
```

Comment: please clarify. Did you add supervisor to create more processes running some module?

Comment: the application launch a supervisor that execute many workers. the problem is that now we use scripts *.sh to launch many instances. What i did is to add a gen_server and a super_supervisor tou launch many instances from erlang. but my config still parsed many times in every instance that my super_supervisor launch.(hope clearer)

Answer (score 1):

It is uncommon to start applications from supervisors or modules under supervisors. The preferred way is to use application dependency to make sure all applications are started, and in the right order.

However, if you want some configuration to be available from several different applications without having to parse the configuration more than once, maybe the gproc library is what you are looking for?
https://github.com/uwiger/gproc

gproc can be used to efficiently set global configuration and much more. Even in a distributed environment.

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer, but the problem is that the application already exists and i have to distribute it for a project (i am a student), and it's the first time i use Erlang. i just want to move the configuration parse from the old application to the new one. (apologize for my english).

Comment: So the only way for you to pass the configuration is by the application start function? In that case I would probably start it from somewhere else and not from a supervisor. Supervisors are generally for starting and supervising processes within the same application. I have a feeling that your teachers may want you to do something else here. You should probably check with them.